# Gauge/chart that "fills" an image rather than a plain circle

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, highcharts

I am trying to create a donut chart/gauge, that illustrates a % amount of something. This value will increase over time, until at somepoint its full/complete

However, the complexity is that instead of just a plain circle/donut shape, I want to illustrate a circle pattern being filled up as the value increases.

Below is an example of a highcharts gauge filled to 25%.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yyrr09nw/2/)

`See Fiddle Example`

And below is a picture (based on a random design from Shutterstock), of the effect I am attempting to achieve.

[image: Example Image]

Would drawing this with SVG be the best way to do it, or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought on this: make a reverse image - the image is white (or whatever your background color is), and the design is transparent; place the image over your donut chart, so that the donut segment colors show through the transparent portion of the design. IMO the SVG would be much more complex, but maybe someone more familiar with working with SVG would disagree. My second thought on this: this is probably going to be a pretty terrible way to actually display data...¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @jlbriggs The above design is not representative of what the final image will look like, its some nice wavy lines around a cirlce essentially, plus the data is displayed as text values as well, but I do get what you are saying about being not totally awesome from a data display point of view. Thats an interesting idea, to overlay a transparent pattern on top of the gauge. I will give it a try and report back!